# Missing "messages" window after compilation in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12. When I run "make project", "debug" or "run" task it does some compiling, shows little bubble that there are warnings, shows grayed-out tool window "message" and after few seconds it hides the nameplate of messages window.

Why is compile log missing? What to do to fix this? I'd like to see (in IDE) what causes those warnings...

PS: I'm not sure, but it might started doing this when I started using Scala (it's now a mixed Scala-Java project).

Answer (score 11):

If you've previously selected "Hide Warnings" then the Messages window is unavailable if there are no compilation errors. It is not even possible to show the empty window using View->Tool Windows-> Message or Alt-0.

Solution:

1. introduce a compilation error
2. build, the Messages window should reappear to show your error (or at least be accessible via the View menu)
3. go to the Messages window and deselect Hide Warnings
4. fix the compilation error
5. Rebuild Project and all your warnings will be visible

(I had the same symptoms on 13.0.2 and this worked for me)

Comment: I don't see "Hide Warnings" in the Messages window in 13.1.3

Answer (score 8):

For me, it pops up on "Rebuild Project". Maybe that helps.

Comment: Well, yes, on rebuild it doesn't hide. But it's not of much use for me, because rebuilt of the whole project takes quite some time to complete (I stated in question that I'd like to solve it for make, run and debug tasks).

Comment: I got the same problem with GRADLE, a rebuild fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The window should be there any time IDEA compiles the code. (If there is a not a code change, and you rerun something there is no compiling done and the message window will not show). It is accessible (by default) via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (Zero, not the letter 'Oh') or via *View > Tools Windows > Messages*

You may have a combination of some tool window settings causing this.

1. If all the tool window buttons are hidden, the messages tool window will be as well. You can toggle this setting via *View > Tool Button* or the [image] icon in the very bottom left corner of the IDE. To temporarily show the buttons when hidden, hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd> twice, holding it down on the second hit.
2. If the messages tool window is not set to "Docked Mode" and "Pinned Mode" it will close after the compile.

If the above is not the issue, make sure you are using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA, v12.1.6, and the latest version of the scala plug-in, v0.22.302 (Go to  *Settings > [IDE Settings] > Plugins* and look for the scala plug-in).  Those versions work as expected for me.

Comment: I have just updated to the newest version (I'm running same verions as you are), but the problem persists. Messages window cannot be opened by shortcut, via menu or tool window buttons (in menu it's gray - disabled, tool button is not present and shortcut does nothing). I can only see in event log for example this: "Compilation completed successfully with 8 warnings in 34 sec", but that's all I can find about compilation...

Comment: My only other suggestion is to disable all third party plug-ins (i.e. any plugin that is not labeled as "bundled") and restart IDEA. It's possible a plug-in is causing an issue. I've seen cases of bugs in third party plug-ins cause some strange issues.

Comment: I have disabled all non-bundled plugins (except the Scala one), but the behaviour is still same :_(. Thank you for trying.

Comment: I got completely the same problem. After coding for some time in with Scala and Play plugins the Messages menu option under Tool Windows became disabled.
It even is disabled while I have compilation errors. It is very inconvenient to work with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like u do not have any errors and warnings! In this case in Idea "Messages" tool window auto disappears. I hade the same issue and passes half an hour to understand the reason!

Comment: I don't think that is my case. It *does* show me how many warnings I got, but not the actual warnings (as I wrote in the question)...